# checking if the variable exists. [weird]

Tags: javascript

I am having a weird problem here.

I am trying to check if the variable exists

I have

```
for(var i=0; i<6; i++{
  if(results[(i+1)].test){
    results[(i+1)].test=i + 'test';
  }
}
```

I know results(6).test is undefined and I need to add that extra index to check if the variable exists. I keep getting console error saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
```

I thought `if(results[(i+1)].test)` would check if the variable exists for me

I also tried

```
if(typeof results[(i+1)].test !='undefined'){
 results[(i+1)].test=i + 'test'
}
```

but still getting error. How do I fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: ok. i got it. I just prove that I need a break now. thanks all!

Comment: maybe the problem is that your iterator does not actually iterate in your array : it iterates from 0 to 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're checking whether foo.test is undefined, but your problem is that foo itself (in this case `results[i + 1]`) is undefined.

You need to check that first, eg.:

```
if (typeof results[i+1] != "undefined") {
    // do stuff with results[i+1].test, or results[i+1].whatever
}
```

Comment: Note that you can do a check for test in the same if, `if (results[i+1] && results[i+1].test)`

Answer (score 1):

you need to assign results(6) to be an object before you can check if .test exists.  Like you said results(6) is undefined which means when you try to call results(6).test you will get the error you describe.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't check the contents of results array.

You should do this:

```
if(typeof results[(i+1)] !== 'undefined'){
 results[(i+1)].test=i + 'test'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

is results[(i+1)] defined?

```
if(results[(i+1)] && results[(i+1)].test){
  results[(i+1)].test=i + 'test';
}
```